# Trying to initiate PointF with a parameter

Tags: c#, plot

Edit: Thank you all, guys. I m indebted to you.

I'm working on a program which plots a function between two values. Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public class E
    {
        public static double A;
        public static double B;
        public static double C;
        public static int s1;
        public static int s2;
        public static int K=(s2 - s1) * 18;  
    }

    public Form2(double a, double b, double c, double s1, double s2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        E.A = a;
        E.B = b;
        E.C = c * 1.3333;
        E.s1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
        E.s2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);

        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);

        Calc();
    }

    public PointF[] p = new PointF[E.K]; //Value in E.K isn't applied here :(

    private void Calc()
    {
        for (int x = 18 * E.s1; x < 18 * E.s2; x++)
        {
            double res = (E.A * Math.Pow(x, E.B) + E.C);
            p[x - 18 * E.s1] = new PointF(x, (float)res); 
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float Y = (float)E.C;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(203, 203 + 14 * (-Y));
        if (E.B == 0 || E.B == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1F);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1F, -0.05F);
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, p);

    }
```

I did some analysis, and found that when `E.K` goes inside the `PointF` function, it turns to 0, therefore the program gives `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Do you guys have any suggestions or alternative ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/213671) to understand why I have edited your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do withe order of object construction / initialization.
The problem is that `E.s1` and `E.s2` are not initialized so consider the following:

```
public class E
{
    ...
    public static int s1;
    public static int s2;
    public static int K=(s2 - s1) * 18;
}

// outside of a constructor
public PointF[] p = new PointF[E.K];

public Form2(double a, double b, double c, double s1, double s2)
{
    // inside the constructor
    E.s1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
    E.s2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);
}
```

Static field initializers are executed before type initializers, and instance initializers are executed before constructors. So when a new instance of `Form2` is created the following occurs:

1. Initializes all static fields of `Form2`, if there are any (but there aren't).
2. Calls the type initializer for `Form2`, if there is one (but there isn't)
3. Initializes all instances fields of `Form2`, if there are any.

   - Initializes `p` but since it's using `E.K`, at this point it initializes the `E` class.

     1. Initializes all static fields of `E`, if there are any:
     2. `K = (s2 - s1) * 18` but since `s1` and `s2` are not initialized this evaluates to `K = 0`.
     3. Calls the type initializer for `E`, if there is one (but there isn't)
4. Calls the constructor for `Form2`, if there is one

   - `E.s1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);` and `E.s2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);`
     But at this point that doesn't have any effect on `p` because it's already been initialized.

This can be confusing and tricky. For this reason it's strongly recommended that you avoid this kind of structure. Use constructors to control the order in which instance members are created and type initializers to control the order in which instance members are created. Also, avoid using static fields as a simple grab-bag for properties, especially when those properties are changing in the lifetime of the program. I'd recommend refactoring your class into something like this:

```
public class E
{
    public double A;
    public double B;
    public double C;
    public int s1;
    public int s2;
    public int K { get { return (s2 - s1) * 18; } }
}

private E e;
private PointF[] p;

public Form2(double a, double b, double c, double s1, double s2)
{
    ...
    e = new E();
    e.A = a;
    e.B = b;
    e.C = c * 1.3333;
    e.s1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
    e.s2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);
    p = new PointF[e.K];
    ...
}

private void Calc()
{
    for (int x = 18 * e.s1; x < 18 * e.s2; x++)
    {
        double res = (e.A * Math.Pow(x, e.B) + e.C);
        p[x - 18 * e.s1] = new PointF(x, (float)res); 
    }
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float Y = (float)this.e.C; // this.e avoids confusion with parameter e
    ...
}
```

Of course the `E` class is somewhat redundant now, all of it's fields could just as easily be stored directly in `Form2`, but this at least makes it easier to pass all these fields to another class if need be (which may be why you chose to use statics in the first place).

I'd also recommend using more than one or two character names for classes or fields. It makes it very difficult to tell what the code is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you change the values of `s1` and `s2`, the value of `K` will **NOT** update automatically.  To make it work like you'd expect, change `K` to a readonly **Property** so it is calculated with the current values of `s1` and `s2`:

```
public class E
{

    public static double A;
    public static double B;
    public static double C;
    public static int s1;
    public static int s2;

    public static int K
    {
        get
        {
            return (s2 - s1) * 18;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not the only thing wrong with OP's code; it won't fix the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.